# C++ Program Issue with Saving Attributes to a Class

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and do not have a lot of experience with coding in general. I'm having a hard time figuring out what the issue is with my code as everything I've tried doesn't seem to fix the issue. In the driver.cpp file, there is an addCourses function that utilizes another addCourse function that is in a student.cpp file. As you can see in the code, the numCourses is supposed to increment every time the function is utilized (if it satisfies the if statement). Now, while running the function, the numCourses does increase, however it doesn't save to the student. For example, if later on in the program I decide to display how many courses the student has, it will display 0, which is the default value, rather than the incremented value. The coursePrefix, courseNum, and courseName also don't save in the long run and the printSchedule function in the student.cpp file only displays the blank, default constructor values (I have to remove the if statement also as i = 0 will never be less than numCourses since it's stuck at defaulting to 0). Please keep in mind that this program is for a class and has strict restrictions and I can't really utilize any advanced code. Pretty much what is in the code right now is most of the concepts I have to work with. Also, my teacher said that we may not create setter functions for the numCourses and schedule[] attributes.

driver.cpp file:

```
//Name: Driver

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "student.h"

#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

int getStudents(int, Student[], string);
string findMaxStudent(int, Student[]);
void printStudentTable(int, Student[]);
int getMenuChoice();
int getStudentOption(int, Student[]);
void addCourses(Student);

enter code here

//comfirm error message for adding too many courses
//may need if statement in addCourses func to utilize true or false

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]){

    int numStudents, userChoice, studentOption;
    Student students[MAX];
    string maxStudent;

    if(argc != 2){
        cout << "Correct usage:" << endl << argv[0] << " filename" << endl;
    }
    else{
        string file = argv[1];

        numStudents = getStudents(MAX, students, file);

        if(numStudents >= 0){

            maxStudent = findMaxStudent(numStudents, students);

            do{
                userChoice = getMenuChoice();

                switch(userChoice){
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1: printStudentTable(numStudents, students);
                        break;
                    case 2: studentOption = getStudentOption(numStudents, students);
                    addCourses(students[studentOption - 1]);
                        break;
                    case 3: studentOption = getStudentOption(numStudents, students);
                        students[studentOption - 1].printSchedule();
                        break;
                    case 4: cout << endl << "The student with the highest gpa is: " << maxStudent << endl;
                        break;
                    default: cout << "Please enter a valid option" << endl;
                        break;
                }
            }while(userChoice != 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int getStudents(int maxSize, Student students[], string file){

    int numStudents, number, i = 0;
    string firstName, lastName;
    float gpa;

    ifstream fin(file.c_str());

    if(fin){
        while(fin && i < maxSize){
            fin >> number >> lastName >> firstName >> gpa;
            students[i].setNumber(number);
            students[i].setLastName(lastName);
            students[i].setFirstName(firstName);
            students[i].setGpa(gpa);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "Sorry, could not open " << file << " for reading" << endl;
    }

    fin.close();

    numStudents = i - 1;

    return numStudents;
}

string findMaxStudent(int size, Student students[]){

    string maxStudent;
    float maxValue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(students[i].getGpa() > maxValue){
            maxValue = students[i].getGpa();
            maxStudent = students[i].getFirstName() + " " + students[i].getLastName();
        }
    }

    return maxStudent;
}

void printStudentTable(int numStudents, Student students[]){

    cout.width(8); cout << left << "First";
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "Last";
    cout.width(6); cout << left << "Number" << endl;
    cout << "======================" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
        cout.width(8); cout << left << students[i].getFirstName();
        cout.width(8); cout << left << students[i].getLastName();
        cout.width(6); cout << left << students[i].getNumber() << endl;
    }
}

int getMenuChoice(){

    int menuChoice;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "STUDENT MANAGEMENT SYSTEM" << endl;
    cout << "================================" << endl;
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "1." << "Display Students" << endl;
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "2." << "Add Courses" << endl;
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "3." << "Display Student Schedule" << endl;
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "4." << "Find Highest GPA Student" << endl;
    cout.width(8); cout << left << "0." << "EXIT" << endl;
    cin >> menuChoice;

    return menuChoice;
}

int getStudentOption(int numStudents, Student students[]){
    
    int optionNum, i;
    
    do{
        cout.width(8); cout << left << "Option";
        cout.width(8); cout << left << "First";
        cout.width(6); cout << left << "Last" << endl;
        cout << "======================" << endl;
    
        for(i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){
            cout << i + 1;
            cout.width(7); cout << left << ".";
            cout.width(8); cout << left << students[i].getFirstName();
            cout.width(8); cout << left << students[i].getLastName() << endl;
        }

        cout << "Choose the student option number: ";
        cin >> optionNum;
    }while(optionNum > i || optionNum <= 0);

    return optionNum;
}

void addCourses(Student student){

    int numCourses, number;
    string prefix, name;
    Course course;

    if(student.getNumCourses() < MAX_COURSES){
        do{
            cout << "How many courses would you like to add? ";
            cin >> numCourses;
                if(numCourses + student.getNumCourses() > MAX_COURSES){
                    student.print();
                    cout << " already has " << student.getNumCourses() << " out of " << MAX_COURSES << " courses" << endl;
                }
        }while(numCourses + student.getNumCourses() > MAX_COURSES);
        
        if(numCourses + student.getNumCourses() < MAX_COURSES){
            for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
                cout << "Enter the course prefix, number, and name: ";
                cin >> prefix >> number >> name;

                course.setPrefix(prefix);
                course.setCourseNum(number);
                course.setCourseName(name);

                if(student.addCourse(course)){
                    
                }
                else{
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        student.print();
        cout << " has a full schedule" << endl;
    }
}
```

student.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h"

void Student::setNumber(int newNum){

    number = newNum;
}

int Student::getNumber() const{

    return number;
}

void Student::setFirstName(string newFirst){

    firstName = newFirst;
}

string Student::getFirstName() const{

    return firstName;
}   

void Student::setLastName(string newLast){

    lastName = newLast;
}

string Student::getLastName() const{

    return lastName;
}

void Student::setGpa(float newGpa){

    gpa = newGpa;
}

float Student::getGpa() const{

    return gpa;
}

int Student::getNumCourses() const{

    return numCourses;
}

Course* Student::getSchedule(){

    return schedule;
}

Student::Student(){

    number = 0;
    numCourses = 0;
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
    gpa = 0;
}

Student::Student(int newNum, int newNumCourses, string newFirst, string newLast, float newGpa, Course newSchedule[]){

    number = newNum;
    numCourses = newNumCourses;
    firstName = newFirst;
    lastName = newLast;
    gpa = newGpa;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COURSES; i++){
        schedule[i] = newSchedule[i];
    }
}

Student::Student(const Student& rhs){

    number = rhs.number;
    numCourses = rhs.numCourses;
    firstName = rhs.firstName;
    lastName = rhs.lastName;
    gpa = rhs.gpa;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_COURSES; i++){
        schedule[i] = rhs.schedule[i];
    }
}

void Student::print(){

    cout << getFirstName() << " " << getLastName();
}

void Student::printSchedule(){

    for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
    cout << schedule[i].getPrefix() << schedule[i].getCourseNum() << ":  " << schedule[i].getCourseName() << endl;
    }
}

bool Student::addCourse(const Course& newCourse){

    if(numCourses < MAX_COURSES){
        schedule[numCourses] = newCourse;
        numCourses++;
    
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;;  
    }
}
```

student.h file:

```
#include <string>
#include "course.h"

#define MAX_COURSES 7

using namespace std;

#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Student{

    int number, numCourses;
    string firstName, lastName;
    float gpa;
    Course schedule[MAX_COURSES];

    public:
    //Setters
    void setNumber(int);
    void setFirstName(string);
    void setLastName(string);
    void setGpa(float);
    
    //Getters
    int getNumber() const;
    string getFirstName() const;
    string getLastName() const;
    float getGpa() const;
    int getNumCourses() const;
    Course* getSchedule();

    //Constructors
    Student();
    Student(int, int, string, string, float, Course[]);
    Student(const Student&);

    void print();
    void printSchedule();
    bool addCourse(const Course&);
};

#endif
```

Comment: Too much code for a question here... you should provide minimal code that reproduce your problem. Maybe your problem is that you have variables with same name and expect a single variable. Also using a debugger would really help.

Comment: Your edit invalidated the answer given, and as such it was reverted. It also was made after you accepted and upvoted the answer. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299405/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void addCourses(Student student){
```

This function, `addCourses()` makes changes to this `student` parameter, such as calling its `addCourse()` method.

In C++, function parameters, by default, are ***passed by value***. This means that this `student` parameter ***is a copy*** of whatever `Student` object was passed to this function. This `addCourses()` function, effectively makes changes to a copy of the passed-in parameter:

```
addCourses(students[studentOption - 1]);
```

When `addCourses()` returns `students[studentOption - 1]` remains completely unchanged because it was ***passed by value***, and `addCourses()` made changes to a copy of this object.

You have two possible solutions here:

1. Pass parameters by reference.
2. Explicitly `return` the modified `Student` object from `addCourses()`.

> Also, my teacher said that we may not create setter functions for the
> numCourses and schedule[] attributes.

If your teacher already explained what references are, how to use them, and how to pass parameters by reference, then this is obviously what you must do, it's a trivial change and the rest of the code remains as is. Otherwise your function should `return` its updated `Student` object, and then the returned objects gets saved, something like:

```
students[studentOption-1] = addCourses(students[studentOption - 1]);
```